# Необходимо заменить часть jsonb_set в большом json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Подскажите, есть json вида:

```
[{"teacher": {"name": "Елена","surname": "Васина", "patrName": "Крыш","department": {"name": null, "Id": {"code": "9.1.4.8.6.5", "codeSystem": null, "displayName": null}}}]
```

мне необходимо запросом изменить code в department.id., при этом не повредив другие данные.
Наткнулась на ф-цию jsonb_set, но воспроизвести ее не выходит.

Пробовала следующим образом:

```
UPDATE personal ps set personal_school = jsonb_set (personal_school -> 'teacher' -> 'department'-> 'Id'->'code', '"8.11.4.87"') where ps.personal_id = '877'
```

Выходит ошибка вида:

```
 function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
```

Подсказка: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

personal - это таблица хранящая информацию о школьном персонале
personal_school - это поле таблицы содержащий json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем *JSON* на верхнем уровне почему-то массив из одного
элемента.  Это ошибка?  Если да, то вот верное использование функции
`jsonb_set`:

```sql
jsonb_set(perosnal_school, ARRAY['teacher', 'department', 'Id', 'code'], '"8.11.4.87"')
```

Если же в вашем *JSON* действительно массив, то в путь надо
добавить индекс:

```sql
jsonb_set(perosnal_school, ARRAY['0', 'teacher', 'department', 'Id', 'code'], '"8.11.4.87"')
```

Comment: вы имеете ввиду "teacher"? да, это единственный элемент, он как блок, который содержит в себе остальную информацию. Там помимо департамента есть и другие, но я не стала их приводить. Попробовала провести ваш запрос, выходит ошибка: path element at position 1 is not an integer: "teacher", он воспринимает его как вещественный тип.

Comment: @Лидия Посмотрите ещё раз на ваш *JSON.*  Он начинается с квадратных скобок.  Понимаете?

Comment: Да, кажется поняла, да у нас есть два элемента, я этого не указала, то есть по сути так UPDATE personal ps set personal_school = jsonb_set (personal_school -> 0 -> 'teacher' -> 'department'-> 'Id'->'code', '"8.11.4.87"')

Comment: @Лидия  См. правку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось, разобралась!